# Sound wont play or play for millisecond

Tags: android, audio, titanium

In Titanium, When the window opens the sound should autoplay . Sometimes it does but mostly it doesnt and sometimes it plays for a millisecond. As the hund.js opens the sound should play.
I have checked the mp3clips and there is nothing wroing with them.

the soundbit: http://pastie.org/8729002

the full code for the win + soundbit: http://pastie.org/8729003

Im new to programming so I really cant figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving player.play(); to the very bottom after hundwin.open();

The hundview may be taking focus away from your global player.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. Annoying. But thanks!